# Display list of variables in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I have to print/display the values of few variables in a MVC view. How can I do this..

```
public ActionResult DisplayVariables()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";           
        {               
           //After some process/logic.. variables get assigned values here..
                int var1 = xxxxxx;
                int var2 = xxxxx;
                int var3 = xxxxxx;
                int var4 = xxxxx;    
        }
        return View()  //I want to display variables values with lables here in this 
                       //view. I already have a view with name "DisplayVariables"
    }
```

Comment: Send off a `Dictionary<String,Object>` to the view and iterate over it? Or possibly use reflection and automate the process (assuming you're just stripping properties off the `ViewBag`)

Comment: and can you show your view definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used   expando object to do this. Please see my response below..

```
public ActionResult DisplayVariables()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";    

    dynamic Model = new ExpandoObject();

    {               
       //After some process/logic.. variables get assigned values here..

            int var1 = xxxxxx;
            int var2 = xxxxx;
            int var3 = xxxxxx;
            int var4 = xxxxx;   

           Model.var1 = var1;
           Model.var2 - var2;  
           Model.var3 = var3;
           Model.var4 - var4;  
    }

    return View(Model)  //I want to display variables values with lables here in this 
                   //view. I already have a view with name "DisplayVariables"
}
```

and in the View.. I have

```
  <h2><%=Model.var1%></h2>
```

How is this solution.. seems to work for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in the view by doing something like

```
@ViewBag.Message.var1
```

It would be better to create a view model though and pass that to your view.

Comment: please see the solution I came up with.. . how does that look?

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a very basic example of how you'd create a strongly typed view, a viewmodel, and pass data.

Define a view model:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.ViewModels
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string Var1;
        public string Var2;
        public string Var3;
    }
}
```

Populate it in your controller:

```
public ActionResult DisplayVariables()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Var1 = "Foo",
        Var2 = "Bar",
        // ...
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Finally, declare the model in your view (in DisplayVariables.cshtml)

```
@* Note the small 'm' here.  You'll probably need to 
   put a namespace in front of the type name as well. *@
@model MyNameSpace.ViewModels.MyViewModel

@Model.Var1<br />
@Model.Var2<br />
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's a bit old post now but it could save time for others.
I done a Partial View which use reflection to display objects properties

```
@using System.Reflection;
@{
    Object l_o = ViewBag.ObjectToDisplay;
}
<style type="text/css">
    table,th,td
    {
        border:1px solid green;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:3px;
    }
    th
    {
        background-color:green;
        color:white;
    }
    #display-title
    {
        font-size:large;
        color:green;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div id="display-title">@l_o.GetType().Name</div>
    <table> 
    <tr>
        <th>Property</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (PropertyInfo l_info in l_o.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        <tr> 
            <td> 
                <div class="display-label" style="text-align: right;"> 
                    @l_info.Name 
                </div> 
            </td> 
            <td> 
                <div class="display-value"> 
                    @l_info.GetValue(l_o, null) 
                </div> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    }
    </table>
</div>
```

Then i use this as

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.Partial("ObjectPropertiesView") 
</body>
</html>
```

Do not forget to set the ViewBag.ObjectToDisplay in your controller.